# how to sort two arrays together where the first one is sorted using bubble sort?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

i have two arrays one is holding students id numbers and the second one holding there grades .. 
i want to to insert a grade to the grade's array in a sorted way .. where i assume that the array before was sorted.
my problem is that i want to keep the student's array sorted also according to the grade's array for example ..

> grades array=[100 90 80]
>
> students_id array=[11 22 33]

and i want to insert grade 95 with id 44 then i will be having :

> grades array=[100 95 90 80]
>
> students_id array=[11 44 22 33]

//
any idea of how i can do this ? i thoght i might insert the grade to the array and then use bubble sort for the first array but i didn't know how to keep the other one sorted too :\

```
void insertGrade(int* grades, int* students_id, int id , int grade){


}


void bubble_sort(int* array, int n)
{
  int c, d, t;

  for (c = 0 ; c < ( n - 1 ); c++)
  {
    for (d = 0 ; d < n - c - 1; d++)
    {
      if (array[d] > array[d+1])
      {
        /* Swapping */

        t = array[d];
        array[d]   = array[d+1];
        array[d+1] = t;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you learned about structures yet?  That’s what should be used. If you’ve not covered them yet, you’ll need to swap elements in both arrays when you do the swap.

Comment: Why do you implement a sorting algorithm, instead of using the Standard C ones?

Comment: Unless bubbleSort is a requirement here, the way to go is to place the grade  in a position where the grades array is still sorted, this way you don't need to sort the grades array again, but you also already know the index where you need to insert the student's ID

Comment: it is not a requirement actually but i thoght that it was a good idea to use bubble sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a 2nd array into the function.  Swap items in array2 at the same time you swap items in array1.

```
void bubble_sort(int* array, int* array2, int n)
{
  int c, d, t;

  for (c = 0 ; c < ( n - 1 ); c++)
  {
    for (d = 0 ; d < n - c - 1; d++)
    {
      if (array[d] > array[d+1])
      {
        /* Swapping */

        t = array[d];
        array[d]   = array[d+1];
        array[d+1] = t;


        t = array2[d];
        array2[d]   = array2[d+1];
        array2[d+1] = t;      
      }
    }
  }
}
```